# Django: Some of the attribute of a model shows None on template if it's empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Some of the attribute of a model shows None on page if it's empty and I don't know why.

For example,

`models.py`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

and `html`

```
{{ user.nickname }} # shows None
{{ user.bio }} # shows nothing
```

What is the difference and how can I prevent it from showing None?

Comment: how you pass data in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well because you are using `CharField` and `TextField`.

you can use `default` template tag to change the output

```
{{ user.nickname |default:"Your custom word" }}
```

or check if value is present then only display it

```
{% if user.nickname %}
   {{ user.nickname }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So it shows `None` if it's `CharField`? I didn't know that. Thanks.